# function crashes depending on function argument definition - double free or corruption

Tags: c++, bspline

I have defined a class for the evaluation of bspline basis functions. I have nowhere used pointers, or new delete etc.  The class is the following:

```
class bspline_basis{

    //private:
    public:
            int k;                                          /*! order of Bspline basis */
            int nbreak;                                     /*! Dimension of breakpoints vector. */
            int nknots;                                     /*! Dimension of knots vector. */
            int nbasis;                                     /*! Number of basis functions */




            vector<double> breakpts;                        /*! Represents strictly increasing values of knots, excluding all multiplicities */
            vector<double> knots;                           /*! Raw knot vector of BSpline basis, it may contain multiple entries due to multiplicity */

            vector<double> Bix_nonzero;                     /*! size: (k). Stores  nonzero components of bspline basis */
            vector<double> Bix;                             /*! size: nbasis Stores  all  components of bspline basis.  Not necessary - remove? */


            int find_knot_span_of_x(const double &x);                                       /*! Returns integer i: t_i <= x < t_{i+k}. Upon call it stores i in i_saved */          
            pair<int,int> find_nonzero_basis_at_x(const double &x);                         /*! Returns first, last index of nonzero basis B_i(x) at particular x. */
            pair<int,int> find_base_nonzero_interval(const double &x);                      /*! Returns first (i) , last (i+k) index of knots t_i at particular x. */


            int i_saved; // Temporary saves for speed up
            double x_saved;  // Temporary saves for speed up

            /* !ESSENTIAL ROUTINES FOR EVALUATION! Add as optional argument another knot vector for use in evaluation of integrals */
            void eval_nonzero_basis(const int &i, const double &x);         /*! Evaluates non zero basis functions at x */
            void eval_Bix(const int &i, const double &x);                    /*! Evaluates all basis functions at x */

            /*! Default clamped  knot vector constructor */
            bspline_basis(const vector<double> &_breakpts, const int &_k);
            /* Evaluation functions */
            double get_Bix(const int &i, const double &x);                   /*! Value B_i(x) */


};
```

The function that is transparent to the user and evaluates the functions B_i(x) is

```
get_Bix(const int &i, const double &x);
```

When I use it inside a for loop, with a variable integer i, everything works great, that is, in this example:

```
// some constructor of class mybasis
for(double x=0; x<=10. x+=0.01)
     {
     cout<< x << " ";
     for (int i=0; i<nbasis; ++i)
            cout<< mybasis.get_Bix(i,x)<<" ";
     cout<<endl;
     }
```

correct values are printed. However if I define a constant integer for the first argument of the function, like in this example:

```
int idx=3;
for(double x=0; x<=10. x+=0.01)
     {
     cout<< x << " ";
    //for (int i=0; i<nbasis; ++i)
            cout<< mybasis.get_Bix(idx,x)<<" ";
     cout<<endl;
     }
```

I get the following error:

```
*** Error in `./test_class.xxx': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000740280 ***
```

when I run the code in gdb, and backtrace it, I get the following message:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7530bb9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linu/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff7533fc8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff756de14 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff767c668 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff757a0ee in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimised out>, str=0x7ffff767c798 "double free or corruption (out)", action=1) at malloc.c:4996
#4  _int_free (av=<optimised out>, p=<optimised out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
#5  0x00000000004039ac in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>::deallocate (this=0x7fffffffdc70, __p=0x608280) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:110
#6  0x00000000004031be in std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffffffdc70, __p=0x608280, __n=15) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:174
#7  0x00000000004030b3 in std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffdc70, __in_chrg=<optimised out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:160
#8  0x00000000004028ed in std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffdc70, __in_chrg=<optimised out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:416
#9  0x00000000004017aa in bspline_basis::eval_Bix (this=0x7fffffffdd40, ii=4, x=@0x7fffffffdd10: 0.01) at bsplines_stackoverflow.hpp:247
#10 0x0000000000401f59 in bspline_basis::get_Bix (this=0x7fffffffdd40, i=4, x=@0x7fffffffdd10: 0.01) at bsplines_stackoverflow.hpp:331
#11 0x000000000040214e in main () at test_class.cpp:31
```

The problem must lie in the functions

```
double bspline_basis::get_Bix(const int &i, const double &x)
    {

    if (i<0 || i> nbasis){
    DEBUG(i);
    std::cerr<< "Index of Bix out of range, aborting ..." << endl;
    throw 0;
    }

    if (x==x_saved && i==i_saved) {
            return
                    Bix[i];
    }else if ( x != x_saved &&  i == i_saved){

            eval_Bix(i_saved,x);    // Evaluate all nonzero and store to Bix. 
            x_saved=x;              // Store x for subsequent evaluations. 

            return
                    Bix[i];

    }else {

            // a. Find knot span of x: 
            find_knot_span_of_x(x);
            // b. Evaluate all nonzero Bix and pass them to Bix: 
            eval_Bix(i_saved,x);

            x_saved=x;              // Store x for subsequent evaluations.
            i_saved=i;              // Store knot span i for possible subsequent evaluations.

            return
                    Bix[i];

    }



}
```

and

```
/*!
Wrapper function for eval_nonzero_basis. Passes nonzero basis values to vector<double> Bix. 
*/
void bspline_basis::eval_Bix (const int &ii, const double &x){

    //pair<int,int> i_start_end = find_nonzero_basis_at_x(x);
    int istart= ii-k+1;
    pair<int,int> i_start_end = make_pair(istart,ii);

    // Evaluate all nonzero entries. for this index. 
    eval_nonzero_basis(i_start_end.second, x);

    // Initialize (to zeros) temporary vector of dimension nbasis 
    vector<double> Bix_temp(nbasis,0.0);

    // Pass nonzero entries to temporary vector 
    for(int j= i_start_end.first; j <= i_start_end.second; ++j)
            Bix_temp[j] = Bix_nonzero[j-i_start_end.first];

    // move temporary vector to Bix
    Bix=Bix_temp;
}
```

I cannot understand how it is possible to get an error when I defined the first argument outside the loop. Any help much appreciated.

**update:** Please let me clarify that the problem is not because the index (idx=3) is outside the allowed range interval. If this was the case the first for loop would crash. Variable nbasis much greater than 3.

**update 2:**  Following @Adrian suggestion, I've made Bix_temp an element of the class, and re-run the code. Again the code crashes, but know it produces some output (values x and infs). This is the new output of the debugger:

```
9.97 inf 
9.98 inf 
9.99 inf 
10 inf 
0.002867sec
4.78333e-05min
*** Error in `/home/foivos/Documents/Grav_Ast/BSplines/Genetic_Algorithms/tests/test_new_Jeans/bsplines_class/test_class.xxx': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000608180 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7530bb9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7530bb9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff7533fc8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89 
#2  0x00007ffff756de14 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff767c668 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff757a0ee in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimised out>, str=0x7ffff767c798 "double free or corruption (out)", action=1) at malloc.c:4996
#4  _int_free (av=<optimised out>, p=<optimised out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
#5  0x00000000004039e8 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<double>::deallocate (this=0x7fffffffdda8, __p=0x608180) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:110
#6  0x00000000004031fa in std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fffffffdda8, __p=0x608180, __n=15) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:174
#7  0x00000000004030ef in std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fffffffdda8, __in_chrg=<optimised out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:160
#8  0x0000000000402929 in std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffdda8, __in_chrg=<optimised out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:416
#9  0x0000000000402646 in bspline_basis::~bspline_basis (this=0x7fffffffdd30, __in_chrg=<optimised out>) at bsplines_stackoverflow.hpp:57
#10 0x00000000004022b6 in main () at test_class.cpp:22
(gdb) frame 9 
#9  0x0000000000402646 in bspline_basis::~bspline_basis (this=0x7fffffffdd30, __in_chrg=<optimised out>) at bsplines_stackoverflow.hpp:57
 57 class bspline_basis{
(gdb) info args
this = 0x7fffffffdd30 
__in_chrg = <optimised out>
(gdb)
```

Again let me emphasize that when I use the for loop index i I don't get any errors.

**update 3:** Found the bug, it was conceptual and inside the function

```
get_Bix(const int &i, const double &x)
```

Specifically, in the following lines of code:

```
// Was using the same index i, for different x, which was a mistake and was causing troubles. 
}else if ( x != x_saved &&  i == i_saved){

        eval_Bix(i_saved,x);    // Evaluate all nonzero and store to Bix. 
        x_saved=x;              // Store x for subsequent evaluations. 

        return
                Bix[i];

}else {
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: That's what's usually the purpose of a debugger is for, not a SO question.

Comment: Hmm. It does not look like double free since I do not see a delete so I assume the problem is corruption possibly caused by stepping outside the bounds of one or more of your vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 if (i<0 || i>= nbasis){
```

instead of

```
 if (i<0 || i> nbasis){
```

at the top of get_Bix.

I'm guessing you're in 3D, in which case you'll have components 0, 1 and 2, but not 3.

Comment: Hi thanks, the problem is not in the dimensionality of the basis, since I have more that 15 coefficients, that is i \in [0,14], so idx=3 is within range. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

There's a destructor in the stack trace, and it must be that of Bix_temp at the end of eval_Bix.

I really don't know why it's happening, but making Bix_temp a member of the class would almost certainly fix it. You'd then have the hassle of zeroing it every time, but that's faster than the construction and destruction anyway.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks again. I've followed what you said, didn't fix the problem. It is in my understanding that the problem is caused (somehow?) by the variable int idx. The remarkable thing is that in the first version of the for loop there is no problem. Again, thanks.

Comment: Buoah! This is a nasty one. Can you post the new stack trace? The old one said it was crashing in the destructor of some vector of double inside evalBix. If you really did what I said then there is no destructor of a vector in eval_Bix, so the stack trace must have changed. As for your "why does it depend on that int" logic, all I can say is that in the past I only ever gave myself a headache by thinking that way.